# SQL query how to get the local variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, query-string

I have this query and I want to get "**page**" variable which is created:

```
SELECT *, (rowNum / 5) + 1 as page
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY items.id_item ASC) as rowNum
    FROM items INNER JOIN utilizadores ON items.autor = utilizadores.id_user
) x
WHERE (rowNum / 1000) + 1 = 1
```

How can I get it in the query to make a procedure to search.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_items_by_page
@page int
AS
SELECT *, (rowNum / 5) + 1 as page
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY items.id_item ASC) as rowNum
    FROM items INNER JOIN utilizadores ON items.autor = utilizadores.id_user
) x 
WHERE (rowNum / 1000) + 1 = 1 //the required condition to query is in bottom
GO
```

**and page = @page;**

Comment: what happens if you just add `AND page = @page` in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: This does not make sense.  You are only selecting one value and you want that to equal the input parameter.  There is some part of the logic you are not explaining well because you don't need the query if the only result is the input parameter

Comment: Invalid column name 'page'.

Comment: sorry it is corrected.

Comment: fix that invalid column name issue like this: `where ((rowNum/5)+1) = @page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_items_by_page
@page int
AS
SELECT x.*, (rowNum / 5) + 1 as page
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY items.id_item ASC) as rowNum
    FROM items INNER JOIN utilizadores ON items.autor = utilizadores.id_user
) x 
WHERE (rowNum / 5) + 1 = @page
GO
```